# JobExecutionContext is null in skip policy

Tags: spring

Below is my simple step builder....I want the jobexecution context in all phases to retrieve job parameters such as file name, file path, other parameters...

Basically i want to register CSV errors in csv file along with incoming csv record data. Also, want to append the error records in the same CSV in all phases for the failed records....So if some error got occurred, i want to continue the processing and register all the errors to the csv file...some error would happen in reading the record, some error would happen in inserting the records into database.

```
    SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder = steps.get("employeeJob")
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(10)
                .reader(employeeFlatFileItemReader) 
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(new EmployeeSkipPolicy())
                .listener(new EmployeeSkipListener())
                .listener(itemProcessListenerSupport())
                .processor(employeeProcessor);

@Slf4j
@JobScope
public class EmployeeSkipPolicy implements SkipPolicy {

@Value("#{jobExecution.executionContext}")
private ExecutionContext executionContext;

private JobExecution jobExecution;


@BeforeStep
public void initWriter(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();

}

@Override
public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable inThrowable, int inSkipCount) {
   executionContext is null
   jobExecution is null
}
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Your configuration is wrong. Scopes only work with spring managed instances, you are creating a new instance yourself. The same applies for registering the callbacks like `@BeforeStep` etc. (It needs to be a listener for that not a policy) and the evaluation of `@Value`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please kindly help me with a correct configuration for the above task? I spend a lot of time but couldn't fix it

Comment: As stated it needs to be managed by Spring. So you need to make it a bean. Construct the object in an `@Bean` method that returns it, call that method instead of doing` new YourObject()`.